# How to get id of a item in list view when we click the item?

Tags: android, mysql

I am working with a project to show images in a list view, and when we click any of the image in list view,then go to the next intent. While when I click, the id of a particular item is not passing to other intent. I don't know what to do.

**Main Activity.java**

```
List<GetDataAdapter> GetDataAdapter11;

RecyclerView recyclerView;

RecyclerView.LayoutManager recyclerViewlayoutManager;

RecyclerView.Adapter recyclerViewadapter;

String GET_JSON_DATA_HTTP_URL = "http://192.1622/.22/new.php";
String JSON_IMAGE_TITLE_NAME = "image_title";
String JSON_IMAGE_URL = "image_url";

JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest ;

RequestQueue requestQueue ;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_tab_activity_1);
    GetDataAdapter11 = new ArrayList<>();

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerview1);

    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

    recyclerViewlayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);

    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(recyclerViewlayoutManager);


    JSON_DATA_WEB_CALL();


}

public void JSON_DATA_WEB_CALL(){

    jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(GET_JSON_DATA_HTTP_URL,

            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {

                    JSON_PARSE_DATA_AFTER_WEBCALL(response);
                }
            },

            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                }
            });

    requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

    requestQueue.add(jsonArrayRequest);
}

public void JSON_PARSE_DATA_AFTER_WEBCALL(JSONArray array){

    for(int i = 0; i<array.length(); i++) {

        GetDataAdapter GetDataAdapter2 = new GetDataAdapter();

        JSONObject json = null;
        try {

            json = array.getJSONObject(i);
          //  GetDataAdapter2.setImageTitleNamee(String.valueOf(json.getInt(String.valueOf(JSON_id))));

            GetDataAdapter2.setImageTitleNamee(json.getString(JSON_IMAGE_TITLE_NAME));

            GetDataAdapter2.setImageServerUrl(json.getString(JSON_IMAGE_URL));

        } catch (JSONException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        GetDataAdapter11.add(GetDataAdapter2);
    }

    recyclerViewadapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(GetDataAdapter11, this);

    recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerViewadapter);


}
}
```

**RecyclerViewAdapter.Java**

```
public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {

Bitmap bitmap;
Context context;
List<GetDataAdapter> getDataAdapter;
ImageLoader imageLoader1;
 int id;


public RecyclerViewAdapter(List<GetDataAdapter> getDataAdapter, Context context) {

    super();
    this.getDataAdapter = getDataAdapter;
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recyclerview_items, parent, false);

    ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(v,context,getDataAdapter);

    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder Viewholder, int position) {

    GetDataAdapter getDataAdapter1 = getDataAdapter.get(position);

    imageLoader1 = ServerImageParseAdapter.getInstance(context).getImageLoader();

    imageLoader1.get(getDataAdapter1.getImageServerUrl(),
            ImageLoader.getImageListener(
                    Viewholder.networkImageView,//Server Image
                    R.mipmap.ic_launcher,//Before loading server image the default showing image.
                    android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert //Error image if requested image dose not found on server.
            )
    );


    Viewholder.networkImageView.setImageUrl(getDataAdapter1.getImageServerUrl(), imageLoader1);
    Viewholder.ImageTitleNameView.setText(getDataAdapter1.getImageTitleName());

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {

    return getDataAdapter.size();
}

class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

    public TextView ImageTitleNameView;
   // public TextView id;
    public NetworkImageView networkImageView;

    List<GetDataAdapter> getDataAdapter ;//= new List<GetDataAdapter>();
    Context context;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView,Context context,List<GetDataAdapter> getDataAdapter) {

        super(itemView);
        this.getDataAdapter=getDataAdapter;
        this.context=context;
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);

        ImageTitleNameView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView_item);
        networkImageView = (NetworkImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.VollyNetworkImageView1);
        id = Integer.parseInt(((TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.pic_id)).getText().toString());


    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        int position = getAdapterPosition();
        GetDataAdapter getDataAdapters=this.getDataAdapter.get(position);
        Intent intent=new Intent(this.context,Secondpage.class);

        intent.putExtra("image_title",getDataAdapters.getImageTitleName());
        Log.e("id","id of clicked image" +ImageTitleNameView);
        intent.putExtra("image_url",getDataAdapters.getImageServerUrl());
        Log.e("id","id of clicked image" +networkImageView);
       intent.putExtra("id",getDataAdapters.getId());
         Log.e("id","id of clicked image" +id);
        this.context.startActivity(intent);

    }
}
```

Comment: I can't see what this has to do with MySQL

Comment: Wt about image_title and image_url. Are these values going  in Secondpage.class ?

Comment: no, image_title and image url is also not going

Comment: Is the `onClick` method excuted?

Comment: @xiaoyuan  yes onclick is executed.

Answer (score 0):

```
view.setTag(id);
```

in onBindViewHolder and

```
view.getTag();
```

in onClick will solve your problem

Comment: sir, what is set Tag?

Comment: we can set a value to view by using set-tag function and that value can be retrieved using get-tag.

Answer (score 0):

At first, make sure you are getting the position of clicked item and then get Item from the ItemList

Try this way:

```
  int pos = (int) v.getTag();
  Item item =ItemList.get(pos);
```

and then try to get id from this item (i.e item.getId)

Answer (score 0):

Add ClickListener in onBindViewHolder and remove onClick from ViewHolder

```
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder Viewholder, int position) {

        GetDataAdapter getDataAdapter1 = getDataAdapter.get(position);

        imageLoader1 = ServerImageParseAdapter.getInstance(context).getImageLoader();

        imageLoader1.get(getDataAdapter1.getImageServerUrl(),
                ImageLoader.getImageListener(
                        Viewholder.networkImageView,//Server Image
                        R.mipmap.ic_launcher,//Before loading server image the default showing image.
                        android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert //Error image if requested image dose not found on server.
                )
        );


        Viewholder.networkImageView.setImageUrl(getDataAdapter1.getImageServerUrl(), imageLoader1);
        Viewholder.ImageTitleNameView.setText(getDataAdapter1.getImageTitleName());

        Viewholder.networkImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
           int position = getAdapterPosition();
            GetDataAdapter getDataAdapters=this.getDataAdapter.get(position);
            Intent intent=new Intent(this.context,Secondpage.class);

            intent.putExtra("image_title",getDataAdapters.getImageTitleName());
            Log.e("id","id of clicked image" +ImageTitleNameView);
            intent.putExtra("image_url",getDataAdapters.getImageServerUrl());
            Log.e("id","id of clicked image" +networkImageView);
            intent.putExtra("id",getDataAdapters.getId());
            Log.e("id","id of clicked image" +id);
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    }



    class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder  {

        public TextView ImageTitleNameView;
       // public TextView id;
        public NetworkImageView networkImageView;

        List<GetDataAdapter> getDataAdapter ;//= new List<GetDataAdapter>();
        Context context;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView,Context context,List<GetDataAdapter> getDataAdapter) {

            super(itemView);
            this.getDataAdapter=getDataAdapter;
            this.context=context;

            ImageTitleNameView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView_item);
            networkImageView = (NetworkImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.VollyNetworkImageView1);
            id = Integer.parseInt(((TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.pic_id)).getText().toString());

        }
    }
```